# От добра добра не ищут

Tags: фразеология

Интересует пословица "от добра добра не ищут".
Прочитала тут вопрос про "Бог не выдаст, свинья не съест" и вспомнила, что у меня тоже есть пословица, смысл которой я понимаю не до конца.
Точнее, у меня есть два варианта трактовки. Первый: если сделал добро, не жди, что тебе сделают добро в ответ. А скорее, наоборот, нагадят. ))))
Второй: во втором случае "добро" употребляется в значении "материальные ценности". Тогда получается: "Не жди награды за сделанное добро".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант правильный? Или неправильны оба?
А еще тоже интересует: пословица это или поговорка?

Comment: Повтор темы http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/16742/фразеология-от-добра-добра-не-ищут-смысл-пословицы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне думается, обе Ваши трактовки не вполне верны. Обычно приведенное Вами выражение употребляется в таком смысле: если у тебя все хорошо, довольствуйся этим, не стремись к большему, не старайся получить еще больше благ, ибо твои стремления не обязательно приведут к лучшему результату. Может случиться и так, что ты погонишься за чем-то бОльшим и потеряешь то хорошее, что у тебя уже было. Это скорее пословица, так как в ней есть назидательное начало